# esconder el boton de borrado en la tabla si coincide con el valor de otra tabla- codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo una tabla de datos con resultados de empresas,la tabla esta compuesta por:

> id y nombre_empresa

y otra tabla con resultados de usuarios compuesta por varios campos como:

> id_user , user_name, user_enterprise  (entre algunos otros que no son
> relevantes)

cada usuario tiene asignado el nombre de una empresa (user_enterprise),pero las tablas no están unidas por ningún tipo de llave cada una tiene sus valores, en el controlador de esta vista, llamo a los modelos de usuarios y empresas y hago que me muestren todos sus datos, aquí es donde tenemos $empresa que muestra todos los resultados de la tabla empresa y $users que muestra todos los resultados de la tabla usuarios.

Con esta información paso a contar mi problema.

En la vista tengo una tabla que muestro todas las empresas cada linea permite ser borrada y tiene dos columnas una que se muestra el nombre y otra que se muestra la acción es decir borrar.

Bien, mi intención es que si en la tabla de empresas existe la empresa con el mismo nombre de algún usuario que esta no permita ser borrada y el botón desaparezca.

Casi tengo el resultado final, pero no termino de entender como hacerlo ya que si coloco el bucle en el botón de borrar muestra todos los resultados y elimina el botón con el mismo nombre, pero de lo contrario a lo que se espera repite el boton de borrar por cada iteracion del bucle.

```
     <tbody>
     <?php
                                                      
   foreach ($empresa as $row) {?>
                                                           
     <tr>
     <td><?=$fila = $row['nombre_empresa'] ?></td>
                                                                
     <td class="project-actions text-right"><?php foreach ($users as $rowUser) { $empresaUser = $rowUser['user_enterprise']; 
     $dataE =[$empresaUser]; print_r($dataE); ?>
     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/admin/empresaList/borrar/<?= $row['id'] ?>" 
      <?php
       if (in_array($fila, array_values($dataE))) { echo 'disabled'; ?> style="visibility:hidden;"<?php } ?> data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
   <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>Empresa vacia (Borrar)</a><?php } ?>
             </td> 
      </tr>
    <?php }?>
 </tbody>
```

dejo un ejemplo del problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como haríais correctamente esto sin que repita mas veces de las necesarias el boton de borrado? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diria que lo que quieres ahora es esto más bien:

```php
$dataE = [];
foreach ($users as $rowUser) { 
    $dataE[] = $rowUser['user_enterprise']; 
}
foreach ($empresa as $row) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$fila = $row['nombre_empresa'] ?></td>
        <td class="project-actions text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/admin/empresaList/borrar/<?= $row['id'] ?>" 
                <?php
                    if (in_array($fila, $dataE)) {
                        echo ' disabled style="visibility:hidden;" '; 
                    }
                ?>
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>Empresa vacia (Borrar)</a>
            <?php } ?>
        </td> 
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

donde primero recopilamos todas las empresas en un único array denominado **$dataE** y despues, durante los ciclos, buscamos a ver si la empresa existe en el.

Comment: justo eso!!! muchas gracias nuevamente!!!!